# what if I uninstall all linux kernel images from my system

Tags: linux-kernel

If I run this:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-*
```

this will definitely remove all linux kernels images from my system.
so the question is will I be able to use my system normally until I reboot or shutdown?

Comment: More-or-less.  I had a system for a while that due to very bad planning I could not fit more than one kernel installed at a time.  Upgrades were a bit nerve wracking...

Comment: You might have problems if you need to load modules from a linux kernel image while your machins is running, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file containing the kernel is only read by the bootloader (e.g. Grub). As part of the boot process, the bootloader loads the kernel file (and might transform it a bit, e.g. decompress it) and transfers control to the code that was stored in that file. After this, the kernel is in memory, and the kernel file is not used. Therefore, removing all kernel images will not impact the operation of your system, up to the time when you reboot, at which point your system won't come back up.

The `linux-image-*` packages contain not only the kernel file, but also loadable modules which contain additional drivers. If you remove the package, drivers that are already loaded will continue to work, but you won't be able to load new drivers into memory for newly connected peripherals. Apart from that, you can continue to use your system normally.